# Group by with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to group by the result bellow:

```
+-------------+------+
| ID | Coln1 | Coln2 |
+-------------+------+
| 10 |     A |  NULL |
| 10 |  NULL |     X |
| 15 |     B |  NULL |
| 15 |  NULL |     Y |
| 20 |     C |  NULL |
| 20 |  NULL |     Z |
+--------------+-----+
```

With the following select:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT
    DB1.dbo.TABLE1.id AS ID,
    DB1.dbo.TABLE1.Coln1 AS Coln1,
    NULL AS Coln2
FROM
    DB1.dbo.TABLE1
UNION
SELECT
    DB2.dbo.TABLE2.id AS ID,
    NULL AS Coln1,
    DB2.dbo.TABLE2.Coln2 AS Coln2
FROM
    DB2.dbo.TABLE2
) AS A
GROUP BY
    ID,
    Coln1,
    Coln2
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Expecting this:

```
+-------------+------+
| ID | Coln1 | Coln2 |
+-------------+------+
| 10 |     A |     X |
| 15 |     B |     Y |
| 20 |     C |     Z |
+--------------+-----+
```

With no luck. Tried to use some `HAVING` with no luck neither. Thanks for any information on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `aggregate function` should help you. Aggregate function will eliminate the `NULL` values.Try this

```
SELECT ID, max(Coln1), max(Coln2)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY
ID
```

Update your query like this..

```
SELECT ID,
       Max(Coln1),
       Max(Coln2)
FROM   (SELECT DB1.dbo.TABLE1.id    AS ID,
               DB1.dbo.TABLE1.Coln1 AS Coln1,
               NULL                 AS Coln2
        FROM   DB1.dbo.TABLE1
        UNION
        SELECT DB2.dbo.TABLE2.id    AS ID,
               NULL                 AS Coln1,
               DB2.dbo.TABLE2.Coln2 AS Coln2
        FROM   DB2.dbo.TABLE2) AS A
GROUP  BY ID
ORDER  BY ID ASC
```

Comment: Thanks. My case is more complex than the example I post. I am using `UNION` with some `NULL` columns. Gonna try your solution.

Comment: Without looking into data it is not possible to comment. According to ur example there is no need of having

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change
Max function is used to select highest values & this function is very helful for avoiding for NULL values

```
SELECT ID, max(Coln1), max(Coln2)
FROM ID, Coln1, Coln2
GROUP BY
ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing a union?

```
SELECT
    t1.id AS ID,
    t1.Coln1 AS Coln1,
    t2.Coln2 AS Coln2

FROM
    DB1.dbo.TABLE1 t1

    JOIN DB2.dbo.TABLE2 t2
         ON t1.id = t2.id
```